# Cron and etherwake on Raspbian

Tags: cron, raspbian, wake-on-lan

I wrote a small application, which runs `etherwake`. From `bash` it works fine and wakes up another PC. But if it is launched from `crontab`, then nothing happens.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and how to solve it?

Note: Maybe it matters, that the app is written with Qt/C++, `etherwake` runs via QProcess and OS is Raspbian on [Raspberry Pi Zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am replying to this message because I was struggling with the same issue.

The problem seems to lie in the `etherwake` path. Crontab runs commands by default in `/bin`. But `etherwake` is located in `sbin`.

```
/usr/sbin/etherwake
```

So instead of doing:

```
00 06 * * * etherwake -i wlan0 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

The proper way is:

```
00 06 * * * /usr/sbin/etherwake -i wlan0 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

This seemed to do the trick for me. Some other people struggling with the same issue have reported that `wakeonlan`:

```
sudo apt-get install wakeonlan
```

solves the problem as well.

Comment: Hi Kevin, if you are planning on "staying in touch with stack exchange", please read on [how to format your answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help). It is really simple, trust me. Cheers and have fun with us.